Nova resource search on click/enter, instead of while typing
I have a resource of 10,000,000+ items and search is slow, especially while it searches for each letter typed.
I have found a half-fix https://nova.laravel.com/docs/resources/the-basics#resource-index-search-debounce and setting to 10 sec but as [enter] and clicking [] both don't search, it forces a wait until the 10 sec is up to search
Is there a setting or some way to search a resource on [enter] or clicking [] instead?
Laravel Nova 3.23
